# How do the Singular Values of a Matrix Change when adding a row with only one entry

Tags: linear-algebra, svd

I have any matrix A and add a row of only zeros except for one 1 in any position.

I have a little prior knowledge about A but nothing that seems very helpful in my eyes (very sparse, most nonzero-elements are either 1, -1 or a real value close to 1)

What can i say about the new singular values of the matrix? I am especially interested in the first and the last singular value.

Is there any hint where to place the 1 in the new row vector to minimize the condition without trying out all possible positions?

I also want to repeat this procedure for a few times, is there any relation to previously added rows?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Brand's paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.laa.2005.07.021) might be of interest.

Comment: While this paper generally goes in the right direction i really can't extract information that would be helpful to me. But that might be my own problem as this topic is still rather obscure to me (i'm an engineer and my education on svd stopped after a short introduction)